# Rain Rig Layers Not Showing Up in the Setting Bar

Tags: layers

I downloaded the rain rig and opened it in Blender 4.0 and the layers settings aren't showing up. Is rain not compatible with 4.0?  (It's the same in object mode and pose mode.

[image: screenshot of the rain rig in the starting pose with the Cloudrig settings tab open. The character dropdown menu on the right side of the viewport is still there, the settings are too. The only thing missing is the layers dropdown in-between them. (The one for fingers and face handles. The pre-opened handles are functioning fine.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it most likely has to do with Bone Layers turning into Bone Collections in Blender 4.0, unfortunately unless the Blender Studio updates the rig i dont think the layers will work properly :c.

a work around you can do is utilize the bone collections just as if they were the layers in your N panel. you might want to rename them for clarity though.